# Prove $\lambda \notin sp(f) \iff \text{Ker}(f-\lambda Id)=\{0\}$

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $E$ be a vector space. Let $f$ be an endomorphisme of $E$. Prove that
>   $$\lambda \notin sp(f)  \iff \text{Ker}(f-\lambda Id)=\{0\}$$
>
> - I'm interested in more ways of proving it

---

We choose to prove this statement by contraposition.

**My proof:**

Contraposition of

$$\lambda\notin sp(f)  \iff \text{Ker}(f-\lambda Id)=\{0\}$$
is
$$\lambda \in sp(f)  \iff \text{Ker}(f-\lambda Id)\neq\{0\}$$

\begin{align}
\lambda\in sp(f) &\iff \exists u\ne0,\ f(u)=\lambda u\\
  &\iff \exists u\ne0,\  f(u)-\lambda u=0\\
  &\iff \exists u\ne0,\  u\in\ker(f-\lambda Id)\\
  &\iff \ker(f-\lambda id)\neq\{0\}
  \end{align}
 - Is my proof correct
 - I'm interested in more ways of proving it .

Comment: Your lambda changes to 1 and vice versa several times, is this intentional?

Comment: it's just small typo

Comment: What is your definition of the spectrum? What you're trying to prove is often taken to be the definition of the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof works perfectly well, so there isn't much feedback to give here.